# Eliminate indent in an \renewcommand\item

Tags: macros, indentation, itemize

I am using a class that contains macros with `\newenvironment` and `\renewcommand\item`. I have been struggling with the indentation, as in a normal `\begin{itemize}` I have found simple solutions to eliminate it, but they don't seem to work in my case.

An important thing is that I have been searching for solutions that eliminate indentation **locally** , as in my document I have other lists that I want to preserve with standard indentation.

The class I am using is the following one (in `\newenvironment{educationlist}` is where I want to eliminate indentation) :

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{tccv}
              [2012/11/09 v1.0
 Two Column Curriculum Vitae]

\LoadClass[10pt]{scrartcl}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}
\RequirePackage[hmargin=1.25cm,vmargin=1.25cm,twocolumn,columnsep=1.25cm]{geometry}
\RequirePackage{bookman,etoolbox,hyperref,needspace,tabularx,xcolor,fontawesome,makecell,graphicx}

% Capitalize words of at least a minimum length (default to 3 chars).
% The text is capitalized before being expanded.
%
% This macro uses Lua to do the job but fails gracefully (that is,
% return the text as is) if \directlua is not available.
%
% |[
% \ucwords[optional: miminum length]{text}
% ]|
\newcommand\ucwords[2][3]{%
    % Fails gracefully if not in LuaLaTeX
    \providecommand\directlua[1]{#2}%
    \directlua{%
    local minlen=tonumber("#1")
    local src="\luaescapestring{\unexpanded{#2}}"
    local dst={}
    for w in src:gmatch('[^\string\%s]+') do
        if w:len() >= minlen then w = w:sub(1,1):upper()..w:sub(2) end
        table.insert(dst, w)
    end
    tex.print(dst)}}

\pagestyle{empty}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\color[HTML]{303030} % Default foreground color
\definecolor{link}{HTML}{506060} % Hyperlinks
\hypersetup{colorlinks,breaklinks,urlcolor=link,linkcolor=link}
\setkomafont{disposition}{\color[HTML]{0058B6}}
\setkomafont{section}{\scshape\Large\mdseries}

% Overrides the \section command to capitalize every
% word for cosmetic purposes and draws a rule under it.
\let\old@section\section
\renewcommand\section[2][]{%
    \old@section[#1]{\ucwords{#2}}%
    \newdimen\raising%
    \raising=\dimexpr-0.7\baselineskip\relax%
    \vskip\raising\hrule height 0.4pt\vskip-\raising}

% Allow conditionals based on the job name. This can usually be set
% from a command-line argument: check fausto.en.tex for an example.
%
% |[
% \ifjob{jobname}{content if matches}{content if does not match}
% ]|
\newcommand\ifjob[3]{%
    \edef\JOBNAME{\jobname}%
    \edef\PIVOT{\detokenize{#1}}%
    \ifdefstrequal{\JOBNAME}{\PIVOT}{#2}{#3}%
}

% Use only \item inside this environment: no other macros
% are allowed:
%
% |[
% \item[optional: what has been achieved]{years}{subject}{notes}
% ]|
\newenvironment{educationlist}{%
    \renewcommand\item[4][]{%
    {\bfseries ##3} & {\raggedleft\scshape ##2} \\
    \ifstrempty{##1}{}{\multicolumn{2}{l}{\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}\scshape ##1\end{minipage}} \smallskip\\}
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}\itshape ##4\end{minipage}}\medskip\\}
    \tabularx{\linewidth}{X r}}
    {\endtabularx}

% Use only \item inside this environment: no other macros
% are allowed:
%
% |[
% \item{fact}{description}
% ]|
\newenvironment{factlist}{%
    \newdimen\unbaseline
    \unbaseline=\dimexpr-\baselinestretch\baselineskip\relax
    \renewcommand\item[2]{%
    \textsc{##1} & {\raggedright ##2\medskip\\}\\[\unbaseline]}
    \tabularx{\linewidth}{rX}}
    {\endtabularx}
```

The Latex document:

```
\documentclass{tccv}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage[gen]{eurosym}

\begin{document}

\section{Education}

\begin{educationlist}

\item[High school diploma]{1988 -- 1992}
     {Informatic engineer}
     {ITIS Castelli, Brescia}

\item{1987 -- 1988}
     {Classical gymnasium}
     {Seminario vescovile, Cremona}

\end{educationlist}

\section{Languages}

\begin{factlist}
\item{Spanish}{Native speaker}
\item{English}{Level C2}
\item{French}{Level C1}
\end{factlist}

\end{document}
```

The result (as you can see, the *Education* section has an indent that I want to eliminate while preserving the one of *Languages*):[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'd say `\tabularx{\linewidth}{@{} X r}`. Put `\newdimen\raising` outside the redefinition of `\section`: it should be at the outer level, as you don't want to allocate a new register for each call of `\section`, do you?

Comment: Okay, thanks for your suggestions. I have tried your solution and actually it corrects the first line of the `\item` (for example in the first item, only *Informatic Engineer* has no indentation) but the other following lines remain with indentation (the ones with `\begin{minipage}`. EDIT: I have applied the same thing to the multicolumns and it also works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a modified class, under the name `mytccv.cls`. The indents came from `\tabcolsep` on the left side of the `tabular` used in the redefinition of `\item`. Also I took the liberty to colour the lines under the section titles (same as font):

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{tccv}
              [2012/11/09 v1.0
 Two Column Curriculum Vitae]

\LoadClass[10pt]{scrartcl}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}
\RequirePackage[hmargin=1.25cm,vmargin=1.25cm,twocolumn,columnsep=1.25cm]{geometry}
\RequirePackage{bookman,etoolbox,hyperref,needspace,tabularx,xcolor,fontawesome,makecell,graphicx}

% Capitalize words of at least a minimum length (default to 3 chars).
% The text is capitalized before being expanded.
%
% This macro uses Lua to do the job but fails gracefully (that is,
% return the text as is) if \directlua is not available.
%
% |[
% \ucwords[optional: miminum length]{text}
% ]|
\newcommand\ucwords[2][3]{%
    % Fails gracefully if not in LuaLaTeX
    \providecommand\directlua[1]{#2}%
    \directlua{%
    local minlen=tonumber("#1")
    local src="\luaescapestring{\unexpanded{#2}}"
    local dst={}
    for w in src:gmatch('[^\string\%s]+') do
        if w:len() >= minlen then w = w:sub(1,1):upper()..w:sub(2) end
        table.insert(dst, w)
    end
    tex.print(dst)}}

\pagestyle{empty}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\color[HTML]{303030} % Default foreground color
\definecolor{link}{HTML}{506060} % Hyperlinks
\hypersetup{colorlinks,breaklinks,urlcolor=link,linkcolor=link}
\setkomafont{disposition}{\color[HTML]{0058B6}}
\setkomafont{section}{\scshape\Large\mdseries}

% Overrides the \section command to capitalize every
% word for cosmetic purposes and draws a rule under it.
\let\old@section\section
\renewcommand\section[2][]{%
    \old@section[#1]{\ucwords{#2}}%
    \newdimen\raising%
    \raising=\dimexpr-0.7\baselineskip\relax%
    \vskip\raising{\color[HTML]{0058B6} \hrule height 0.4pt}\vskip-\raising}


% Allow conditionals based on the job name. This can usually be set
% from a command-line argument: check fausto.en.tex for an example.
%
% |[
% \ifjob{jobname}{content if matches}{content if does not match}
% ]|
\newcommand\ifjob[3]{%
    \edef\JOBNAME{\jobname}%
    \edef\PIVOT{\detokenize{#1}}%
    \ifdefstrequal{\JOBNAME}{\PIVOT}{#2}{#3}%
}

% Use only \item inside this environment: no other macros
% are allowed:
%
% |[
% \item[optional: what has been achieved]{years}{subject}{notes}
% ]|
\newenvironment{educationlist}{%
    \renewcommand\item[4][]{%
    {\bfseries ##3} & {\raggedleft\scshape ##2} \\
    \ifstrempty{##1}{}{\multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}\scshape ##1\end{minipage}} \smallskip\\}
    \multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}\itshape ##4\end{minipage}}\medskip\\}
    \tabularx{\linewidth}{@{}X r}}
    {\endtabularx}

% Use only \item inside this environment: no other macros
% are allowed:
%
% |[
% \item{fact}{description}
% ]|
\newenvironment{factlist}{%
    \newdimen\unbaseline
    \unbaseline=\dimexpr-\baselinestretch\baselineskip\relax
    \renewcommand\item[2]{%
    \textsc{##1} & {\raggedright ##2\medskip\\}\\[\unbaseline]}
    \tabularx{\linewidth}{@{}rX}}
    {\endtabularx}
```

and the LaTeX code:

```
\documentclass{mytccv}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage[gen]{eurosym}

\begin{document}

\section{Education}

\begin{educationlist}

\item[High school diploma]{1988 -- 1992}
     {Informatic engineer}
     {ITIS Castelli, Brescia}

\item{1987 -- 1988}
     {Classical gymnasium}
     {Seminario vescovile, Cremona}

\end{educationlist}

\section{Languages}

\begin{factlist}
\item{Spanish}{Native speaker}
\item{English}{Level C2}
\item{French}{Level C1}
\end{factlist}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove the initial (and final) padding:

```
\newenvironment{educationlist}{%
    \renewcommand\item[4][]{%
    {\bfseries ##3} & {\raggedleft\scshape ##2} \\
    \ifstrempty{##1}{}{\multicolumn{2}{l}{\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}\scshape ##1\end{minipage}} \smallskip\\}
    \multicolumn{2}{@{}l@{}}{\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}\itshape ##4\end{minipage}}\medskip\\}
    \tabularx{\linewidth}{@{}X r@{}}}
    {\endtabularx}
```

Note `\multicolumn{2}{@{}l@{}}` and `\tabularx{\linewidth}{@{}Xr@{}}`

You should also move `\newdimen\raising` outside the redefinition of `\section`:

```
% Overrides the \section command to capitalize every
% word for cosmetic purposes and draws a rule under it.
\let\old@section\section
\newdimen\raising
\renewcommand\section[2][]{%
    \old@section[#1]{\ucwords{#2}}%
    \raising=\dimexpr-0.7\baselineskip\relax
    \vskip\raising\hrule height 0.4pt\vskip-\raising}
```

But probably it's easier without it:

```
% Overrides the \section command to capitalize every
% word for cosmetic purposes and draws a rule under it.
\let\old@section\section
\renewcommand\section[2][]{%
    \old@section[#1]{\ucwords{#2}}%
    \vskip-\ht\strutbox\hrule height 0.4pt}
```

Comment: Removing `\newdimen\raising` causes a compiling error (not sure why).